# SAP WEB IDE - Hybrid App Configuration (Local Add-on) not appearing in Hybrid App Toolkit menu

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

Self explanatory really.

This option is under Project Settings.

It was there, and no error messages are displaying.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .project.json file find projectType property, change to the following

```
"projectType": [ 
    "sap.watt.uitools.ide.fiori", 
    "com.watt.common.builder.sapui5clientbuild", 
    "com.sap.webide.hybrid.cordova" 
],
```

This will enable the Hybrid App Configuration in Project Settings.